# Какая временная сложность counter и sorted?

Tags: python, сложность

```
#1
from collections import Counter

company = {'A': 3.75, 'B': 44.2, 'C': 12.4, 'D': 44.5, 'E': 10.1}
count = Counter(company)

print(count.most_common(3))


#2
company = {'A': 3.75, 'B': 44.2, 'C': 12.4, 'D': 44.5, 'E': 10.1}
income = sorted(list(company.items()), key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)[:3]
print(income)
```

Comment: о каких сложностях вы говорите?

Comment: сортировка в хэш таблциах O(n/klog(n)) подсчет элементов с ключом O(1) всего элементов O(n)

Answer (score 2):

Можно посмотреть исходники модуля [Collections](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/collections/__init__.py) для начала:

```
    def most_common(self, n=None):
        '''List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
        common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.
        >>> Counter('abracadabra').most_common(3)
        [('a', 5), ('b', 2), ('r', 2)]
        '''
        # Emulate Bag.sortedByCount from Smalltalk
        if n is None:
            return sorted(self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

        # Lazy import to speedup Python startup time
        import heapq
        return heapq.nlargest(n, self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1))
```

Как можно видеть, если вызвать `most_common` без параметра, то разницы с `sorted` вообще не будет - будет вызван в итоге он же. А вот при вызове с параметром будет вызвана другая сортировка `heapq.nlargest`, насколько я помню она более эффективная, чем та, которая используется в `sorted`, если нужно взять небольшое число самых больших или самых маленьких элементов.

Про сложность `heapq.nlargest` и сравнение с `sorted` можете попробовать почитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038756/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-heapq-nlargest) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666602/python-heapq-vs-sorted-complexity-and-performance).